# Meaning of "to rolf"

Tags: meaning, slang

We have a little dispute about this in our team at work.

Rolf is a German male name. But someone said, he saw online, that "to rolf" is a verb in American Slang, which means "to vomit".

And indeed on [dict.cc](https://www.dict.cc/?s=rolf) there is an entry in the dictionary saying that.

But in virtually every other source I tracked down, there is no mention of this.

I found three different meanings:

1. Male Name
2. Rolling on laughing floor (?)
3. using a special massaging technique (Rolfing)

So, my question is, is there a possible meaning in any kind of English for "to rolf" that equals "to vomit" or something similar?

Comment: 2) is "ROFL", not "rolf" - "Rolling On the Floor Laughing", though it may be misspelled as "ROLF".

Comment: Yep, "rolf" (or "ralph") is an old US youth term for "vomit".  Been around since the 60s, at least.

Comment: I don't know the phonetic symbols, but I've always heard "R*a*lph" with the "A" sound, not "R*o*lf" with the "O" sound to mean vomit

Comment: using "rolf" to mean "vomit" is the same kind of onomatopoeia as "den [Jörg](http://www.sprachnudel.de/woerterbuch/den+j%F6rg+rufen) rufen" in German.

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach - We're talking about schoolyard slang here, not the OED.  Different terms/pronunciations will be used in different locales, and often a mutated term will be propagated because someone *thought* they head it that way somewhere else.

Comment: I've only ever heard of "rolf" as a verb within the context of the deep tissue massage: see [rolfing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolfing).

Comment: @dlatikay Oh yes!: I've not heard the expression before, but now you mention it, "Jörg" said out loud the drawnout way as in your linked "Sprachnudel" entry actually makes me feel quite queasy, much more than "ralph". I've actually always quite liked the sound of the name "Jörg"; I guess the trick is to not hold on to the "ö" too long!

Comment: Illuminated by the technicolour yarn Billy Connolly tells, of the naive tourists calling for their buddies Ralph and Hughie after a misunderstanding about pints of Heavy ale vs a certain kind of vin-du-pays.

Comment: In the US, at least, the world is definitely "ralph".

Comment: Honestly, if you're trying to avoid every word that's similar to a word or term for vomiting in US English, you have a whole lot of work ahead of you. Powerthesarus for instance lists [462 of them](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/vomit), and I know at least one they missed ("driving the porcelain bus")

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Being from Norway, I instantly recognized what the title was referring to.

Norway also has the male name Rolf, and the slang phrase "rope på Rolf" ("to call for Rolf") means "to vomit". It refers to the pronunciation of "Rolf" being somewhat similar to the sound you make when you vomit

From 1825 to 1920 about 800 000 Norwegians emigrated to America. ([Norwegian Wikipedia article](https://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norsk_emigrasjon_til_USA)). I would not be surprised if they brought slang with them, although I can not find any sources for when the slang appeared in the Norwegian language

Comment: A similar thing happens in Portuguese: "to call for Gregório" («chamar o Gregório») - because for us the name Greg is onomatopoeic for throwing up.

Comment: @ANeves That sounds (literally) like another Norwegian slang phrase for vomiting: "Rope på elgen" ("call for the moose"). The word "elg" ("moose") not being very far from "Greg" in pronounciation

Comment: In Spanish, we have "llamar a Hugo" (to call for Hugo) because if one exaggerates the "go" syllable, it resembles the onomatopoeia for throwing up.

Comment: And now I find Dutch strangely lacking.

Comment: Very interesting. Norwegian immigration to the US would seem a highly likely root, although I can't find anything substantiating this

Comment: Billy Connelly has a routine where he references both Rolf and Huey in the same theme - [Two Scotsmen in Rome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKMQKgSnGy8) [NSFW!]

Comment: In German there's "Jörg anrufen" for the same thing, meaning to call Jörg.

Comment: Swiss Germans are calling Ulrich (or Ueli) in that situation.

Comment: We use this in New Zealand too. Sometimes Rolf, sometimes Ralph

Answer (score 41):

I didn't know of it, but there seems to be a slang expression **to ralph**, meaning "to vomit," according to [this buzzfeed post](https://www.buzzfeed.com/joannaborns/slang-terms-for-vomiting?utm_term=.dgZzxedeQ#.evKPydXdQ):

> 6. Ralph
>      Sorry everyone named Ralph, but you have to admit there’s almost an onomatopoeia to this one. It also kind of seems like something a guy named Ralph would say.

Comment: You could make it a bit more explicit that "to Ralph" means "to vomit", but I think this is the most likely explanation.

Comment: Yes, ralph, spew, hurl...

Comment: Also, originally from Australian slang, but borrowed when I was a teenager in the 80s: "to talk to Huey and Ralph on the great white telephone" is why vomit is also referred to as "huey" or "hughie" in the UK. Again an onomatopoeia from the sounds made while vomiting into a toilet.

Comment: Growing up in the 70's I'd often heard the expression "calling *ralph* in his *buick* from the *porcelain bus*", two of the three euphemisms show up on the buzzfeed post.

Comment: Worth mentioning that while I think _ralph_ is fairly commonly understood in this context, I have never once seen _rolf_, and finding a reference to it seems to be fairly difficult

Answer (score 9):

Try an alternate spelling, replace the "o" with "a".
And/or replace the "f" with "ph" (same English sound).
I believe the name "Rolf" is commonly Anglicized into "Ralph"

Urban Dictionary (https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ralfing) says ralfing is
  "The sound created by somebody noisily vomiting due to excess alcohol consumption"

I've heard this expression for decades in reference to "loud vomiting" (not limited to alcohol vomiting as stated above).

HTH

Comment: Well, in regards to young men there is one particular well known cause of loud vomiting. Once had the (mis-)pleasure to see an 8 foot projectile *ralph* into a garbage pail without a drop on the floor.

Comment: True, however, I heard this long before without the context of drinking. While ralf may be commonly associated with drinking, that isn't always the connotation; there are other causes in "young men" such as eating contests (which may be just as silly/dumb).

Answer (score 0):

There’s a modern disambiguation, now.  “Rolf” is a verb, from the bodywork practice “Rolfing” named after the founder Ida Rolf.

Similar to how Chiropractic work focuses on bone alignment and joints, Rolfing focuses on the fascia, the layers of material holding muscles, tendons, and organs to the frame of the body.

The correct English slang you’re looking for is “Ralph”, as stated above.

Comment: A link, in the answer, confirming this meaning and usage would be great! :)